How to use PUT to add custom taxonomy to Woocommerce Product via REST API
I've been researching this a bit, so I'm not asking just randomly.  There are a few posts/answers that start to address, but they are old(er) or don't all agree on how to handle this.
I want to be able to change the Custom Taxononmy I created called product brands (product_brands) that are assigned to a woocommerce product through REST API.
I added the Product brands to the Woocommerce API using this code:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object', 'uplvl_rest_api_prepare_brands_tax', 10, 3 );
function uplvl_rest_api_prepare_brands_tax( $response, $object, $request ) {

    $product_id = $object->get_id();

    if ( empty( $response->data[ 'product_brands' ] ) ) {
        $terms = [];

        foreach ( wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_brands' ) as $term ) {
            $terms[] = [
                'id'   => $term->term_id,
                'name' => $term->name,
                'slug' => $term->slug,
            ];
        }

        $response->data[ 'product_brands' ] = $terms;
    }

    return $response;
}

This is working (although some examples I saw used $product instead of $object in the arguments)  and I can see my product brands attached when I request a product through API calls using this endpoint /wp-json/wc/v3/products/3130  (the 3130 is an actual product).
I want to be able to PUT back into the system to to change or add product brands back to the product.
My understanding is that I may be able to use woocommerce_rest_pre_insert_product_object to get this done, but I'm not sure how to set it up:
function uplvl_prepare_insert_product( $product, $request ) {

    if ( isset( $request['product_brands'] ) ) {
        wp_set_object_terms($product['id'], $request['product_brands'], 'product_brands');
    }
    return $product;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_pre_insert_product_object', 'uplvl_prepare_insert_product', 10, 2 );

When I do this, I get an error "Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WC_Product_Simple as array"
If I use an actual id instead of $product['id'] in the wp_set_object_terms it does work, so i guess I need to know how to get the id out of the request array.
I'm not sure if I should have used wp_set_post_terms instead of wp_set_object_terms here or not either.
I did see another post about adding new rest endpoints but I'm hoping that is only because those were older posts?

As the error is related to $product['id'] where $product is a WC_Product_Simple object instance, you need to use $product->get_id() to get the product ID.
